# Oracle 18c XE expdp specific schemas in xepdb1

Tags: oracle18c, oracle-dump

I'm running Oracle 18c XE database in CentOS 7 and like to export a specific schema in xepdb1 database.

This doesn't work as system is unable to recognise the schema in xepdb1 database. Any help much appreciated

expdp system/password123 schemas=accts_db directory=accts_bkup_dir dumpfile=accts_db.dmp logfile=accts_db.log

Answer (score 0):

This works for me finally

```
expdp system/********@at-app-prd-02:1539/xepdb1 schemas=accts_db directory=accts_bkup_dir dumpfile=accts_db.dmp logfile=accts_db.log
```

The listener was running on 1539

```
[oracle@at-app-prd-02 ~]$ lsnrctl status

Listening Endpoints Summary...

  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=at-app-prd-02)(PORT=1539)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=at-app-prd-02)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/admin/XE/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))

Services Summary...
```